# How to add event click to a div in web browser C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to set a click event to a div in the web browser control,  that div have no id, so, I searched for it by title.. 
and set a click like  I do with button control, but it doesn't work.
this is my code :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("title").Equals("div_name"))
        {
            link.InvokeMember("click");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

In this case, I've modified an existing solution.  Add a script to do it:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("title").Equals("div_name"))
        {
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            element.text = "function clickTitle() { document.getElementById('" + link.GetAttribute("id") + "').click(); }";
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
            webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("clickTitle");
        }
    }
}
```

It adds a javascript script to click on it and then clicks on it.  It assumes the element has an id.

Comment: It doesn't work, because I want to do the click, not specific something when user click .. I hope that you understand me

Comment: i updated with a very different method...had misunderstood what you had said before